# I wanna disable a canvas and destroy the object when the player leaves the collider

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a animated **UI** and I wanna destroy the object after the player left the Collider and I don't really seem to find a way to do that.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class Crate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float duration;
    public GameObject animateObject;

    public GameObject crateBox;
    public Text crateText;
    public GameObject crateImage;

    public GameObject crate;

    public bool playerInRange;
    private bool crateOpened = false;
    

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (crateOpened == false)
        {
            if (Keyboard.current.eKey.wasPressedThisFrame && playerInRange)
            {
                if (crateBox.activeInHierarchy)
                {
                    crateBox.SetActive(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    crateBox.SetActive(true);
                    crateOpened = true;
                    Animate();
                }
            }

            if (crateOpened == true)
            {
                Destroy(animateObject);
            }
        }
    }

     private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        if(other.CompareTag("Player")) {
            playerInRange = true;
            crateImage.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other) {
        if(other.CompareTag("Player")) {
            playerInRange = false;
            crateBox.SetActive(false);
            crateImage.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    private void Animate()
    {
        LeanTween.scale(animateObject, new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f), duration);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make a animated **UI** and I wanna destroy the object after the player left the Collider and I don't really seem to find a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is in the wrong place:

```
if (crateOpened == true)
{
   Destroy(animateObject);
}
```

Try moving this inside the if statement in `OnTriggerExit2D`. What you are doing now is destroying your `animateObject` before it is animated. What I think you want is for animateObject to be destroyed when the player leaves the collider.